# PHP: how to check if SPECIFIC user is logged in

Tags: php, sql

I want to show specific information only to a certain user, and my sql query was supposed to work but it doesn't.

in login.php there is this code:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $user;
```

where it stores the certain user logged in right now.

but when I apply the following:

```
    $uploaderUsername =$_SESSION['username'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM meeting WHERE status = '$statuscheck' ") or die(mysql_error());
    $uploaderresult = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM meeting WHERE status = '$statuscheck' ") or die(mysql_error());

    if ($result != NULL AND $uploaderUsername = '$uploaderresult') {
```

it shows the content of the 'if' to every user that is logged in.
about status and $statuscheck, it's a variable that exists in only one row and that row has a specific username value - it shouldn't apply to every user.

why does this happen?

Comment: Pretty sure that you need `$uploaderUsername == '$uploaderresult'`. You only have 1 "=" and if statements for PHP require two in this case.

Comment: Your last two queries can be combined into one. Also you shouldn't be using the deprecated ext/mysql functions. You don't even escape anything that goes into your queries meaning that you could be open to SQL injection.

Comment: @Tricky12 i tried that already, if i change it to '==' it doesn't show the content to neither the certain user i want it to show nor the other users

Comment: What is statuscheck??

Answer (score 1):

You have used assignment operator '=' instead of equality operator '=='. Just change it.

Comment: @ WisdmLabs i tried that already, if i change it to '==' it doesn't show the content to neither the certain user i want it to show nor the other users

Comment: @tototororo That means that you are not getting the correct `uploaderresult` from your database. You do need the '==' because that is how you check equality in an if statement. Otherwise, as before, it will trigger when you do not desire. I would wager that `statuscheck` is not what you think it is, and therefore you aren't getting the correct query results.

Comment: @Tricky12 thing is, i tried the query on phpmyadmin directly and it correctly shows the output i want it to, and also ` statuscheck ` does work, at least it works in other functionalities i already applied. it is $statuscheck = 2; , and it checks for rows that have status = 2 and it works. so what else can there be?

Comment: @tototororo The only other thing I can think of is that I don't think you need the single quotes (') around `$uploaderresult` in your comparison.

Comment: @tototororo did you check your result for '$uploaderresult' is array or string?

Comment: @WisdmLabs how can i do this?

Comment: print_r($uploaderresult);

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a WHERE statement to your SQL that checks your username? Something like:

```
$uploaderresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM meeting WHERE status = '$statuscheck' AND username =  '$uploaderUsername'");
```

I maybe missing something...

Comment: still the same, shows the content to every user logged in...i can't understand why is this happening unfortunately

Comment: Can you echo $_SESSION['username'] to verify your'e setting it properly?

Comment: yes, i tried that too, it correctly shows the user currently logged in

Comment: I'm currently working this
`   $uploaderresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM meeting WHERE status = '$statuscheck' AND username =  '$uploaderUsername'");
  if ($uploaderresult != NULL) {
`
is it the if statement that is faulty?

Comment: Looks ok..try to hard code the username into the sql

Comment: SELECT * FROM meeting WHERE status = '$statuscheck' AND username = 'Jim'

Comment: well, i'm trying to make the system multi-user and by using that sql query it reverts back to single-user :P

Comment: Yes but for testing purposes. Just to see if it works. The WHERE statement is wrong if there are multiple results being returned or you have extra rows of data for that user.